# Why does my summation program throw a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, file, numberformatexception

I want to read the numbers from the file and sum up the total, but I cannot seem to process the data properly. It is successfully outputting the numbers but is not successfully summing them up.

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();      
        FileWriter output = new FileWriter("number.txt");
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
            str.append(r.nextInt(100) + " ");
        }
        output.write(str.toString());
        System.out.println(str.toString());
        output.close();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("number.txt");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line = input.readLine();
        int total = 0;

        while (line != null) {
            System.out.print(line);
            total += Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

And the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Q1.main(Q1.java:42)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the exact problem?

Comment: i had add exact problem

Comment: For future reference you do not need to write solved in the title if you have accepted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't append a ending line char to the output.
Try out this snippet:

```
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

    FileWriter output = new FileWriter("number.txt");

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {

        str.append(r.nextInt(100)).append('\n');

    }
    output.write(str.toString());
    System.out.println(str.toString());
    output.close();

    FileReader reader = new FileReader("number.txt");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);

    String line;
    int total = 0;

    while ((line = input.readLine())!=null) {

        total += Integer.parseInt(line);
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

If the output looks weird, examine where the output is being created.  That is usually where you will find the problem.  Also added in some small changes to give you an idea of a different way you could go about it that might make your life easier.

Comment: thanks no error but it not sum up, it combine all the number only ,like this
97391923299076738135619960262691746686422177425392249757826155068821163550716489167881513649252331611235828926462318759040918186954410396994942719737765256423910296328392278329124954147702475614925

Process completed.

Comment: It actually is, it's just getting appended onto the end of the line.  Try removing the System.out.print(line); in the loop.  It should work now @Mr.Yw

Comment: Ya,it work,  thanks a lot, u give me an idea. I replace with System.out.print(line+" ")